# Fetching Document-id using where clause (Firebase Firestore with Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: This is my firebase firestore database]

I want to get document-id where field "Name" = "Karan Bapat". I tried using the where clause but I can get only the field values not the document id for my precise field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to get the document ID, which is `Jcrat...CEkn2`, you have to call [getId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getId()) on the [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) object like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference customerRef = db.collection("Customer");
Query queryByName = customerRef.whereEqualTo("Name", "Karan Bapat");
queryByName.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document != null) {
                    String docId = document.getId();
                    Log.d(TAG, "docId: " + docId);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
docId: Jcrat...CEkn2
```